# Get-ChildItem Confusing Results

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I'm running Get-ChildItem but its returning TWO results which is confusing me ... why ?

```
Get-ChildItem "$env:ProgramFiles\Google\Drive File Stream\" -Filter 'GoogleDriveFS.exe' -Recurse
```

here's the output:

```
  Directory: C:\Program Files\Google\Drive File Stream\56.0.11.0


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         3/30/2022  11:38 AM       53664656 GoogleDriveFS.exe


    Directory: C:\Program Files\Google\Drive File Stream\56.0.9.0


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         3/24/2022   8:02 AM       53662040 GoogleDriveFS.exe
```

Surely I'm not running two separate versions of googleDrive ??

Comment: What's confusing about that output? You're using the `-Recurse` switch and it has found 2 files with the name in the directory hierarchy.

Comment: You might not be _running_ two separate versions, but that doesn't preclude having 2 separate versions _installed_ :)

Comment: ah strange - I just wasn't aware of that but I guess its possible and maybe even makes sense

Comment: @Tony if you want the _newest version_, and the parent folders are always named for the version in the form `X.Y.Z.z`, then you could do: `Get-ChildItem ... |Sort-Object { $_.DirectoryName -as [version] } |Select -Last 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the `-Recurse` switch and it found multiple files by the same name in subfolders of the tree you ran `Get-ChildItem` from. `-Recurse` will recursively check inside other containers, which since you're using the `FileSystem` provider, means it will recursively look in nested directories.

We can't tell you why there are two and this isn't the community to ask about it (hint: try asking on [Super User](https://superuser.com)). But `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` is telling you exactly what you've asked of it: recursively search for `GoogleDriveFS.exe` in subdirectories of `$env:ProgramFiles\Google\Drive File Stream`.